AWS Amplify multiple custom batch mutations/resolvers
Given the docs, I have created a batch put resolver for a given type/table, but wondering how another batch put resolver should be created.
Successfully created:
type Todo @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String
}

type Mutation {
  batchCreateTodo(todos: [BatchCreateTodo]): [Todo]
}

input BatchCreateTodo {
  id: ID
  name: String!
  description: String
}

But let's say I would like to create another batch put resolver/mutation, should this be done like:
type Mutation {
  batchCreateTodo(todos: [BatchCreateTodo]): [Todo]
}

type OtherMutation {
...
}

Or like this:
type Mutation {
  batchCreateTodo(todos: [BatchCreateTodo]): [Todo]
  someOtherBatch(things: [BatchCreateThings]): [Things]
}

How would the cdk-stack.ts for the second batch mutation know that it is for the Things model? Is this the differentiated by the fieldName/typeName in the resolver?:
const resolver = new appsync.CfnResolver(this, "custom-resolver", {
      apiId: cdk.Fn.ref(retVal.api.replaceWithAPIName.GraphQLAPIIdOutput),
      fieldName: "querySomething", 
      typeName: "Query", // Query | Mutation | Subscription
      requestMappingTemplate: requestVTL,
      responseMappingTemplate: responseVTL,
      dataSourceName: "TodoTable" // DataSource name
    })

